# Why does my router go offline for 30 seconds every 30 mins?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

My cable modem at home (Time Warner Cable) is a DOCSIS 3.0 modem and wireless router in one device. Recently this new thing started happening:

Every 30 mins or so, I go offline from my MacBook connected via Wi-Fi, for about 30 seconds. Then it comes back online. The Wi-Fi connection is still fine. The Mac thinks it's connected just fine. But a ping or traceroute will just hang.

How can I debug why this happens and get it to stop?

Comment: Can you provide the ping output for the period it drops?

Comment: Provide information on the modem if you don't mind.  In the past when I had this issue, it required my ISP to push a firmware update to my modem, which was extremely sensitive to a noisy connection.

Comment: the ping output is none, I type ping google.com and it just hangs. Okay I will post modem info soon, thanks!

Comment: What you should try do is to ping your router, when the connection is dropped, not Google. That will tell us whether the connection drop is within your LAN (in which case perhaps we can do something about it)or is outside your LAN, in which case you can only complain with your ISP.  Also, you may send an `ARPING` to a neighboring pc, which completely bypasses the router, so we know whether it is your pc or the router. On a Linux system, that would be `arping -I eth0 192.168.1.5` (if there is such an IP in your LAN), for other OSes you ought to look it up.

Comment: i tried to ping the router's IP during a time when it's working and got "Request timeout for icmp_seq"

Comment: device is "Motorola Model SBG6580"